Change number of spaces on internal monitor when an external monitor is connected
I would like to configure the number of spaces on my MacBook running macOS Sequoia as follows:

When no external monitor is attached, I would like to have two spaces on the internal monitor. That is, this is what Mission Control should display on the internal monitor:

Let's call it setup A.

When an external monitor is attached, I would like to have one space on the external monitor and one space on the internal monitor. That is, this is what Mission Control should display on both the external and internal monitors:

Let's call it setup B.


How can I automatically change between setup A and setup B when I plug/unplug an external monitor?

That feature is called Mission Control (see https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/view-open-windows-spaces-mission-control-mh35798/mac for details). What do you expect exactly when no external monitor is connected? That no app windows should be displayed? That's not the way macOS works: app windows are displayed depending on the specific setting for that window (visible or minimized), it doesn't depend on the number of monitors attached to your Mac. If an app window is visible on an external monitor, and you disconnect it, the window will "move" to the internal monitor and still be visible.

"Mission Control" thanks!  It's hard to believe my question isn't clear with the enormous annotated image!  But I will edit it, thanks!  @jaume

Thank you for your edit. What you call "virtual monitor" is called "space". You can configure a different number of spaces on different displays (note that that's a static configuration, independent of the number of displays connected) as follows: open System Settings > Desktop & Dock and enable "Displays have different Spaces" under Mission Control at the bottom of the pane. Then unplug your external display and configure the internal display to have only one space (press Control-Up to display Mission Control and delete all spaces but one). That should do it. Could you try it and report back?

AHHHHHHHHH "SPACE" that makes so much sense.

I will do so in the A.M. TY !!!!!!

(PS its "Displays have separate Spaces" ..

@jaume hmm notice my edit.  I wonder if one has to literally restart?  (It says "log out" in the doco, which makes sense asd that restarts the finder.)

I think what is being asked is that when there is only one physical monitor that there be two spaces, but when there are two physical monitors the need for the second space goes away, replaced by the second monitor.
Thus there are always "two" monitors, case one: physical + virtual; case two: physical + physical. The windows for the "second" monitor would migrate between the virtual space and the physical second monitor depending on connection status.

It might be possible to create and remove a space with Hammerspoon, although the documentation says it is experimental. I have not done this. Hammerspoon: https://www.hammerspoon.org ; spaces module documentation: https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.spaces.html

well @SteveM sure.  As it says: (when no monitors) == two "Spaces".  (when monitor connected) == zero "Spaces".  Pretty straightforward!

Thank you @SteveM for pointing that out, that makes a lot of sense and it is in fact clearly stated in the question after the edit, I got it wrong for some reason. The Shortcuts app doesn't support creating spaces, so Hammerspoon is surely an option.

I've edited and shortened your question to make it clear what your desired setup is. I hope it's OK, otherwise simply revert my edit. A note about spaces: you write in your comment "(when monitor connected) == zero "Spaces"", I understand what you mean, but it's confusing because there's always at least one space (the "physical display" also counts as a space, and the default setup is to have one space). I tried to make that clear in my edit.

@jaume thanks!! also yes, I certainly meant "2" (when NO monitors) and "1" (monitors connected).  The "0" was a typo!

You know, i literally didn't realize, did not notice, that when you have (say) 5 physical monitors, there is a Space on/for each monitor, ie 5 Spaces in the example.  I incorrectly thought they had that as a (single, given) Space comprised the entirety of physical surface available, I now see how it works!  in any event the way you have presented the question is now 100% correct, thanks!!!! @jaume

You can indeed have a single space that encompasses all physical displays if you turn off "Displays have separate spaces". So you were right:-) Spaces work as follows: if the setting is off you have the same number of spaces on both displays. When you unplug the external display, open windows on the external display move to the corresponding space on the built-in display. If it's on you can have a different number of spaces on each display. When you unplug the external display, the spaces on the main display are shown on the built-in display, plus any additional spaces on the extended display.

This means macOS doens't support the setup you describe in your question. As a workaround: a) make sure the built-in display has one space (let's call it space 1) and is the main display (in System Settings > Displays, select "Arrange..." and move the menu bar to the built-in display) b) add a space to your external display so that you have two spaces (space 2 and 3). With this configuration, when you unplug the external display, space 2 merges with space 1, and space 3 moves as-is to your built-in display. Now, if you ignore space 2 and only use spaces 1 and 3, you'll get what you want.

that's quite a lot to digest eh!  thanks !!!

You’re right, I’ve packed quite a lot of information in the comments… If you have a chance to test the workaround in my previous comment, report back and share your feedback, thanks!

You know what, I had a fiddle with the workaround which is damn clever, but the concept of let's say "ignoring that one" throws me off unfortunately!  But it's a great work around!  You know what, surely, someone makes a utility app that "automatically changes such settings".  Actually the Moom guy should do it, or add it to Moom, that would be perfect. (I'm sure you're a Moom user!). Thanks again BTW !!!

A negative answer ("it turns out it's NOT possible to do that") is always very useful to googles trying to figure the same problem, so don't hesitate to put in answer!

@jaume perhaps you should pop in a summary of the info as an answer so the bounty isn't wasted.  Indeed, a negative "unfortunately its not possible" answer is oiften a very good answer

Thank you for coming back to me, I've added an answer. Let's see if it inspires others and you get a better workaround or a real solution :-)

Unfortunately, macOS doesn't natively support the setup you describe in your question.
The reason is that the first space of any connected display "disappears" when it is unplugged. Any windows that were on that display are moved to the first space of another display.
That is, if you have two displays, each one with one space, and you unplug one display, you end up with one space, not two.
Workaround
As a workaround you could do the following:

Open System Settings > Desktop & Dock and enable "Displays have separate Spaces":

This will let you configure a different number of spaces on each display (see below "How do spaces work?" for details).

Make sure the built-in display has one space (let's call it space 1).

Add an additional space to your external display so that you have two spaces (space 2 and space 3).


With this configuration, when you unplug the external display, space 2 merges with space 1, and space 3 moves as-is to your built-in display. Now, if you ignore space 2 and only use spaces 1 and 3, you'll get what you want.
The workaround is not especially elegant and needs getting used to, but I thought I'd share it in case it's helpful.
How do spaces work?
Spaces behave differently depending on whether the connected displays share  spaces:

If the setting "Displays have separate Spaces" in System Settings > Desktop & Dock is off:

then spaces are shared, and you will have the same number of spaces on both displays. In this case, each space "extends" to encompass both displays.
With this configuration, when you unplug the external display, open windows on the external display move to the corresponding space on the built-in display.

If the setting is on, spaces aren't shared and you can have a different number of spaces on each display, and every space is confined to the display where it was created.
With this configuration, when you unplug the external display, the final result depends on which display is the main display.
The main display is the display where the desktop items (like files and folders) will appear. Any other displays that are not mirroring the mail display are called extended displays. You can set the main display in System Settings > Displays by selecting a display and choosing "Main display" from the pulldown menu next to "Use as". For example, in the screenshot below, the external display (on the left) is the main display:

Generally speaking, when the external display is not connected, the spaces on the main display will be shown on the built-in display, plus any additional spaces from the extended display.
For example, if the external display is the main display and has three spaces (1, 2 and 3), and the built-in display has two spaces (4 and 5), when you unplug the external display the built-in display will have four spaces (1, 2, 3 and 5), and all windows on space 4 will move to space 1.
Conversely, if the built-in display is the main display and has four spaces (1, 2, 3 and 4) and the external display has three spaces (5, 6 and 7), when you unplug the external display the built-in display will have these spaces: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 and 7, and all windows on space 5 will move to space 1.


For more information on spaces, see: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/work-in-multiple-spaces-mh14112/15.0/mac/15.0

My only regret is that I have but one bounty to give !!!  TY !
